# interacting with slurm jobs in python

Tags: python, slurm

I need to interact with slurm on a cluster through python. Specifically, I need to submit a bunch of jobs, check which ones succeeded, resubmit those that failed, collect the results, etc. In R, there is a package called `BatchJobs` which provides this functionality. What is the equivalent in Python?

I saw PySlurm around but it looks like that is still under development and wouldn't have all the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 1):

One tool fitting this requirement is [gc3pie](https://github.com/uzh/gc3pie). You might also find [fireworks](https://materialsproject.github.io/fireworks/) interesting although it is a full-fledge workflow system.